# registration on android and saving on database using PHP, MySQL and SQLite

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

many may have ask about this question but i want to ask it anyway..im doing a tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and i kind of remade the whole thing i made the user register name email password and confirm password...but i get this error here **05-08 01:13:42.638: W/System.err(3295): org.json.JSONException: No value for cpassword** after changing the code i then get this error [image: error]

***any ideas are welcome i also want to know `how to get the original password back`***

java code

database handler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String USER = "user";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static String USER_ID = "id";
    private static String USER_UID = "uid";
    private static String USER_NAME = "name";
    private static String USER_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String USER_PASSWORD = "cpassword";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + USER + "("
                + USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + USER_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + USER_UID + " TEXT,"
                + USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String cpassword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USER_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(USER_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(USER_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(USER_PASSWORD,cpassword); // Password

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(USER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("password", cursor.getString(4));
            Log.e(cursor.getString(1)+cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3)+cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USER;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(USER, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

register

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

    Button Submit;
    EditText Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword;

    private static String USER_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String USER_ERROR = "error";
    private static String USER_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    // JSON Response node names
        private static String USER_ID = "id";
        private static String USER_UID = "uid";
        private static String USER_NAME = "name";
        private static String USER_EMAIL = "email";
        private static String USER_PASSWORD = "cpassword";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        ConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmPassword);
        Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);

        Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                String email = Email.getText().toString();
                String password = Password.getText().toString();
                String cpassword = ConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
                 String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@([\\w]+\\.)+[\\w]+[\\w]$";
                if (email.matches(EMAIL_REGEX)){
                    if(password.matches(cpassword)){
                        new MyAsyncTask().execute(name, email,cpassword);
                    }else{
                        Toast ief = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password Does Not Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        ief.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        ief.show();
                    }

                }else{
                    Toast ief = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Incorrect Email format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    ief.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    ief.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void ,JSONObject> {

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        if (params.length != 3)
        return null;

        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
        return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                if (json != null && json.getString(USER_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String res = json.getString(USER_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database

                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        Log.e(json_user.toString(), "Password no value");
                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(USER_NAME), json_user.getString(USER_EMAIL),json.getString(USER_UID), json.getString(USER_PASSWORD));                        


                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        //dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        Toast ief = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Email is Already in Use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        ief.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        ief.show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
}
```

php

index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 * 
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

  /**
 * check for POST request 
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            // echo json with success = 1
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $user["user_uid"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["user_name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["user_email"];
            $response["user"]["password"] = $user["user_password"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["user_uid"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["user_name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["user_email"];
                $response["user"]["password"] = $user["user_password"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

DB_Functions.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_tbl(user_uid, user_name, user_email, user_password, user_salt) VALUES('$uid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt')");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $id = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE user_id = $id");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE user_email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['user_salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['user_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_email from user_tbl WHERE user_email = '$email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Show you code dude. `JAVA, PHP`

Comment: you could see the error `table user has no column name cpassword`. so check out your table to find whether `cpassword` exists

Comment: @krishna thats is what im wondering because this part here is confusing me android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named cpassword (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO user(cpassword,uid,email,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
you can see that user(cpassword,uid,email,name) meaning these are the column in my table right?

Comment: You should make the title more descriptive, not just a collection of tags.

Comment: @HakHak That INSERT statement is for you program to INSERT value into your SQLite database, you will have to go and look into the class where you create your SQLite table. Look for your "CREATE TABE ...." and double check if that column exists.

Comment: @SteD i checked it i will post that class wait as you can see i only have this on my database in sqlite String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + USER + "("
                + USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + USER_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + USER_UID + " TEXT,"
                + USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

Comment: @HakHak Looks ok, I notice that you have a DB version = 5, did you happen to add the cpassword column and not increasing the DB version? If so, the changes wouldn't be called. Another way is to extract the SQLite DB out and have a look at it and confirm if the column exists or not.

Comment: @SteD  how do you extract the SQLite DB?i increase the version together with renaming it but the error is still the same i was thinking maybe the column wasnt create on the old version but then the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

Its json parsing problem check your User_Password key it is USER_PASSWORD = "cpassword" in your Activity code but from server side it is "password" so just remove 'c' from your USER_PASSWORD key. thats it.

Comment: i tried it already still fail...remove c from USER_PASSWORD only how about in public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String cpassword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USER_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(USER_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(USER_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(USER_PASSWORD,cpassword); // Password

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(USER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

Comment: it returns this error now 05-08 03:31:50.670: W/System.err(3738): org.json.JSONException: No value for password

Comment: hey your problem is not in SQLiteDatabase it is in this line db.addUser(json_user.getString(USER_NAME),json_user.getString(USER_EMAIL),json.getString(USER_UID), json.getString(USER_PASSWORD)); "json.getString(USER_PASSWORD)" this tag please Change USER_PASSWORD to "json.getString("password")". then check

Comment: did try but error jay on password on this "json.getString("password")". thanks any for the effort but its SQLite Database i think its not populating and i dont get why

Comment: first just print what you get in json_user.getString(USER_NAME) and ,json.g‌​etString(USER_UID) and json.getString("password") in log and then add itt to sqlite.

Comment: hey problem is object name replace json.getString("password") to json_user.getString("password") thats it. :)

Comment: when using  json_user.getString(USER_NAME) and ,json.g‌​etString(USER_UID) all is ok using password i get error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the error by commenting  `String cpassword = ConfirmPassword.getText().toString();` i dont understand why but now its running lol i just change the cpassword with ConfirmPassword.getText().toString() now its running smoothly

Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                String email = Email.getText().toString();
                String password = Password.getText().toString();
                String cpassword = ConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
                 String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@([\\w]+\\.)+[\\w]+[\\w]$";
                if (email.matches(EMAIL_REGEX)){
                    if(password.matches(cpassword)){
                        new MyAsyncTask().execute(name, email,cpassword);
                    }else{
                        Toast ief = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password Does Not Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        ief.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        ief.show();
                    }

                }else{
                    Toast ief = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Incorrect Email format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    ief.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    ief.show();
                }

            }
        });
```